# How to obtained user's info on startup page of mobille application if he/she is already registered?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing mobile application using phonegap. I want to get information of user if user is already registered (i.e; records already available in database).

On starting when user entered his unique id like Mobile Number and if he/she is already registered with this Mobile No  then his/her full details will be shown to user on next page of mobile application

And I also want my application should be register with only one mobile number.

How it can be possible...plz Help me out

Thanks in advance,

Nikhil Chavan

Comment: Which database [localstorage/SQLite] and where it is located?

Comment: i m using restful webapi service asp.net web api

Comment: my service is located on server

Comment: i want to implement one time login functionality in my phonegap app..i m using asp.net web api as a service..pls help me out for this

Comment: after registering/logging in for the first time, set the login name in localStorage and during next app launch, send the login to your service to determine wether its in database or not and send yourself some response.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax to send and recieve data,

```
function requestDataAtLogin(usermail, password, provider, id, version){
    var dataO={
                'Email':usermail,
                'Pwd':password
            };
    var url="http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/app.dev.web/MobileApp/api/Security/AuthenticateUser";

    $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : url,
                data : JSON.stringify(dataO),
                contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType : "json",
                processData : true, 
                success : loginSuccess,
                            timeout: 50000,
                error : loginFailed
            });
        }

    }
    function loginSuccess(data) {
    alert("success");
    }

    function loginFailed(msg) {   
    alert("failed");
    }
```

In the Web API service,

```
public MobileInitialDataModel AuthenticateUser(InitialRequestModel authenticationDetails)
        {
              //your service code

}

 public class InitialRequestModel
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Pwd { get; set; }

    }

  public class MobileInitialDataModel
    {
        public byte[] Token { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }

    }
```